# How to trigger a downstream pipeline of a protect branch in Gitlab with keyword 'trigger'

Tags: triggers, gitlab, token, pipeline

The error says it has no permission.
The question is how to use the pipeline token in the upstream pipeline/project.
(I know with 'curl' script the token could be set but now I just would like to use the keyword 'trigger') Thanks!

@VonC Thanks for your reply.
Here's the job in the yaml. ‘trigger' is used to start the downstream pipeline.
But since they're different and the downstream pipeline is running against the master pipeline, the guy who triggers the pipeline should be a maintainer of the downstream project. Otherwise, the job will not run and the prompt is 'no permission to trigger downstream pipeline'.

```yaml
trigger-test
  stage: test
  trigger:
    project: myprj/downstream-test
    branch: master
  allow_failure: true
  only:
    - master
```

Comment: Can you edit the question with your current yaml code for your gitlab-ci, and the exact error message you see (copy-paste)?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

You can also use server side git `hooks` and allow `Developer` roles to merge into your `protected` branches.
This will allow any `Developer` to trigger your `protected` branch, but the `hook` will restrict access to actual protected repository based on your rules.

Gitlab also provides very convenient `envs` for the hooks, for example `..gitlab_server_protected_repo.git/custom_hooks/pre-receive`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash 

if [[ "$GL_USERNAME" != @(user1|user2|user3) ]]; then 
  echo "GL-HOOK-ERR: $GL_USERNAME restricted"
  exit 1
fi
```

More on that: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/server_hooks.html

**OLD**

Yep, at this time this is a **big security concern** in Gitlab CI, related links:

- https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/348465
- https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/app/services/ci/create_downstream_pipeline_service.rb#L109-111
- https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/gl-infra/deployer/-/commit/00d61b2852f1a387d498fbe080b9795b755fef9b
- https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/gl-infra/deployer/-/commit/4607032361f826a81840ca68f02741ec0de63562

The workaround is not such satisfying but it works:

1. Make desired branch protect in 'Downstream' repository
2. Create Pipeline triggers (actually this is a token, the name is
   misleading) in 'Downstream' project : Settings -> CI/CD -> Pipeline triggers.
3. As an Admin - locate this token as a Group CI/CD variable (or in the project which will trigger 'Downstream' project) - Group Settings -> CI/CD -> Variables.
4. Use it in you pipeline:

```bash
      curl -X POST \
        --form token=$YOU_TRIGGER_TOKEN_VARIABLE \
        --form ref=target_branch \
        "$CI_API_V4_URL/projects/55/trigger/pipeline"
```

The issue with workaround - UI doesn't visually track relationship between initiated pipeline and downstream.

The other solution which is **not secure**:

1. Create user with Maintainer role (if your protected branch allows to merge only for Maintainers)
2. Create personal user token
3. Locate and use it the same as in previous solution.

Anyone who understand what power does this token provides - can do everything with protected branches via his own .gitlab-ci.yml pipeline, referencing this token.